Knitr package will not install
Looks like my knitr package is damaged.  I removed the package via RStudio but I can not get it to reinstall.
I get the following error message.  I've tried rebooting, installing it directly from R instead of RStudio but not luck.
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
namespace 'xfun' 0.43 is being loaded, but >= 0.44 is required
Calls:  ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'

removing 'C:/Users/ddoyle/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status


"namespace 'xfun' 0.43 is being loaded, but >= 0.44 is required" sounds like you should try install.packages("xfun") to update that package first.
